# Vue.js - inject a v-on button to spawn an overlay from static html sourced from an external source

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Using Axios, I'm pulling in a static HTML file. This part is working

The user clicks on an edit button and I'm going through that static HTML and adding a new class if an existing class exists.

If that existing class exists, I want to add a new button with `v-on` in this static HTML template and re-render the content with this new button in the HTML which then spawns an overlay.

Is there anyway that I can add this new button in my code so that view re-renders and uses the Vue `v-on` directive?

Here is my code:

#### VIEW:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="kbViewer">
        <b-button
          class="request-edit"
          @click="letsEditThisStuff({currentUrl: currentUrl})">Request An Edit</b-button>

        <div v-html="htmlData">
          {{ htmlData }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
data: function () {
  return {
    sampleElement: '<button v-on="click: test()">test from sample element</button>',
    htmlData: '',
  };
},

methods: {
  pullView: function (html) {
    this.axios.get('../someurl/' + html).then(response => {
      let corsHTML = response.data;
      let htmlDoc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(corsHTML, "text/html");
      this.rawDog = htmlDoc;

      this.htmlData = htmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;
    })
  },

  letsEditThisStuff(item) {
    let htmlDoDa = this.htmlData;

    // This doesn't work - I'm trying to loop over the code and find all 
    // of the class that are .editable and then add a class name of 'editing' 
    // to that new class. It works with #document of course...

    for (const element of this.htmlData.querySelectorAll('.editable')) {
      element.classList.add('editing');

      // Now what I want to do here is add that sampleElement from above - or however - 
      // to this htmlData and then re-render it.

      let textnode = document.createElement(sampleElement);

      textnode.classList.add('request-the-edit')
      textnode.innerHTML = 'edit me!'

      element.append('<button v-on="click: test()">test from sample element</button>')

      console.log('what is the element?', element)
    }

    this.htmlData = htmlDoDa
  },
}
```

I know that some of my variables are not defined above - I'm only looking at a solution that helps with this - basically take that stored `data.htmlData`, parse through it - find the classes with "editable" and append a button with a `v-for` directive to that specific node with "editable" ... Unfortunately, the HTML already exists and now I've got to find a slick way to re-parse that HTML and re-append it to the Vue template.

Comment: [This post](/q/31633573/3634538) might help on the templating part.

Comment: Close - but i'm lazy loading each external html file based on what content subject the user is on. I only want to pull these static html documents when the user navigates to the page they may, or may not want to edit.

Answer (score 0):

I found Vue Runtime Template and it works PERFECTLY!

https://alligator.io/vuejs/v-runtime-template/